# Is there any tool available to migrate Oracle tables to Cassandra DB?

Tags: database, oracle, cassandra, nosql, database-migration

How can the Oracle Database Schema, Tables, and Procedures be migrated to Cassandra?
Any tool available to do this work?

Comment: A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no tool because it cannot be done automatically, with the schema only you are lacking some mandatory informations.

To build a good data model with Cassandra you need to know the application queries because it is based on the WHERE clauses that you will create your primary keys.

I did it for the [Pet Clinic Spring Application](https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-reactive) and created a workshop for people who are interested in the process and methodology

- [Slides, Code and Samples](https://github.com/datastaxdevs/workshop-sql-to-nosql-migration)
- [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elRWY8-tMbU)

**High-level principles**

In Cassandra.....

- There is no relationship so most of your foreign keys will lead to new tables, you will join on writes, not on reads (denormalization)
- There are no acid transactions (yet) so the operations should be idempotent as much as possible.
- There are no sequences, you want to leverage on UUID instead
- There are no stored procedures, the intelligence is moved back to the applications.
- Some columns can be multi-valued (`Set`, `List`, `Map`) so some relations one-to-many can be done in the same table.
- You design table models based on your queries. Most of the time it is one query = 1 table. If you need to query the same data with multiple requests you duplicate the data in multiple tables. (Storage is cheap)

**Moving the data**

After the redesign of the schema, you can think of moving the data from Oracle to Cassandra. Multiple ways to do this:

- Export Oracle data to CSV and then import with OSS Tool called **[DS-Bulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/dsbulk-cmd.html)**
- Use a **Spark workflow** to move the data in a distributed way
- Use **Apache Beam** with `JdbcIO` as input and `CassandraIO` as output.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a straight forward way of migrating the data across because Oracle's relational model with the normalised tables isn't a good fit for databases like Cassandra.

Enterprises choose Cassandra because of its availability to operate an internet scale with very fast reads and writes. To achieve this, each of the tables are optimised for reads such that the data is stored in denormalised tables.

You will need to model your data before you can migrate the data. At a high level this involves:

**Step 1** - List all application queries.

**Step 2** - For each application query, design a table such that the data is partitioned based on the filter in the query.

**Step 3** - For each table in Cassandra, export/unload the relevant data from Oracle then bulk-load to Cassandra.

For example, if the application needs to get the details of a user based on their email address, we need to design a table that is partitioned by email which would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users_by_email (
    email text,
    name text,
    username text,
    phone text,
    address text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (email)
)
```

With this table schema, the table can be queried with:

```
SELECT * FROM users_by_email WHERE email = ?
```

If the application needs to retrieve details of a user based on their username, we need to design a table that is instead partitioned by the username like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users_by_username (
    username text,
    name text,
    email text,
    phone text,
    address text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (username)
)
```

and query it with:

```
SELECT * FROM users_by_username WHERE username = ?
```

With denormalisation it does mean that data is duplicated across multiple tables so it's a tradeoff between disk space versus read performance.

Once you have completed the data model for Cassandra, you can migrate the data in several ways. Here is a short list of possible solutions:

1. Export the data from Oracle into CSV files then bulk-load to Cassandra using the [DataStax Bulk Loader (DSBulk)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/overview/dsbulk-about.html).
2. Write a Spark job that would read the data from Oracle, transform the data to match the Cassandra schema, then load the data using the [Spark Cassandra connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector).
3. Write a Java app (or language of your choice) that would read from Oracle and write to Cassandra.

If you decide to go down the CSV route, here are some DSBulk resources with examples to help you get started quickly:

- Blog - [DSBulk Intro + Loading data](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading)
- Blog - [More DSBulk Loading examples](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading)
- Blog - [Counting records with DSBulk](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-counting)
- Docs - [Loading data examples](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/dsbulkLoad.html)

DSBulk is open-source so it's free to use. Cheers!